# Trying to build a tkinter web scraper using regex

Tags: python, regex, user-interface, tkinter, web-scraping

Yes, I am aware of BeautifulSoup. I know how much better it is but unfortunately Regex is my only option right now, and quite frankly I'm stumped.

I've extracted the titles that I need and can get them to print in console, but can't get them to print as a label in tkinter.

This is what happens when it runs:

[image]

I am very appreciative of any advice or help as I have a long couple of nights ahead of me xoxo

Comment: appreciative* I'm v tired.

Comment: In general it is ill-advised to try to parse HTML using some regex (or “regex”) tool.

Comment: why--"my only option right now"?

Comment: It's in the task requirements to not import external modules.

Comment: add return into print_uk definition and use print_uk() inside the Lable

Comment: @Serge That has definitely helped, can't believe I missed that, thanks. Just need to iterate through them now

Comment: Have you tried built-in library `HTMLParser` (2.7) or `html.parser` (3.x)?

Answer (score 1):

add return of the list into `print_uk` definition and use `position` to get element of the list returned by in `print_uk()` inside the `Label` constructor.

To be more cool try `yield` the labels text.